# angular2 upload a safeUrl(using domSanitizer) image to firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm reading an image file and then I wanted to upload it to firebase storage. I'm using this function to read the image data:

```
readImage2(inputValue: any): Observable<any> {
    var file:File = inputValue.files[0];
    const objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var myObs = Observable.create((observer) => {
        observer.next({imageUrl: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL)})
    })
    return myObs
}
```

Then, I'm using `toString()` method on the imageURL to convert it to string and then using

```
firebase.storage().ref(`images/${this.guid()}`).putString(image)
```

to upload the image. However, this uploads some string value which is not the image. How do I convert the safeURL obtained after using sanitizer to a blob or something so that I can upload it to firebase?

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to achieve